# Create Grouped tables in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two models GuidanceSupervisor and GuidanceAdvisor. 
How to create a table like this one in the picture using two models ? I have not tried any thing in the view, but also I have searched for it in many questions and did not find a clear answer for it.

[image]

Comment: So what is the problem. The query? The view? What have you produced already?

Comment: I don't know how to create it with two models ! thats why i am asking , i saw another questions but the answers were not clear to me

Comment: Ok. Can you post an example of the resulting table you want to display? Just the rows/columns for one supervisor will do.

Comment: I have updated it, this image from google , i need something like it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change the names in the image for better understanding. then:

in the view:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   Guidance supervisor name
  </td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <% @GuidanceSupervisor.each do |gs| %>
 <tr>
    <td>
        <%= gs.name %>
    </td>

    <td>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Guidance advisor name
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <% gs.guidance_advisors.each do |ga| %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= ga.name %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <tr>
                        <td>batch</td>
                        <td>student</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td><%= ga.batch.value %>
                        <td><%= ga.student_class.value %>
                    </tr>

                </td>
            <tr>
            <% end %>
        </tr>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

batch.value and student_class.value represents the values to output (.value)

for me this works:

make the table in html first and then iterate over the instance variables, and be careful with the nesting.